# Flask (Как выполнить опредленное действие при нажатии на гиперссылку)

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть шапка сайта, и при определенных размерах, все меню пропадает, появляется иконка, при нажатии, на которую открывается вся остальная часть меню. Как выполнить это действие без js, а с использованием только Flask? JS совсем не знаю(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак! Выучил JavaScript, ушло меньше 2 недель + неделя на ReactJs)